# Convert List to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

Tricky problem here. I'm trying to convert items for a list to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

### Lists

`dynamicTextInDatabase` simply returns all the Enums that are used in my database. Currently only returns 1 and 2. The data class simple holds an int value.

`dynamicTextEnumsInDatabase` is the same list as above just in the class that actually stores my Enums.

`dynamicTextEnumsAll` is a list of all the Enums that are available in my application. Currently: 1, 2 and 3.

`dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable` is a list of all the unused Enums. It combines All the Enums and then removes the ones that are in the database list.

I need to pass the `dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable` to my View via the ViewBag to display in a drop-down list. However, It must be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` rather than a `List`.

### Code

```
        var dynamicTextInDatabase = new List<DynamicTextEnumData>();
        var dynamicTextEnumsInDatabase = new List<DynamicTextEnum>();
        var dynamicTextEnumsAll = new List<DynamicTextEnum>();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list;

        using (var proxy = new Proxy<IDynamicText>())
        {
            dynamicTextInDatabase = proxy.Channel.DynamicTextGetActiveEnums(Helper.GetCallingUser());
        }

        foreach (DynamicTextEnumData item in dynamicTextInDatabase)
        {
            var dynamicTextEnum = (DynamicTextEnum)item.DynamicTextEnum;
            dynamicTextEnumsInDatabase.Add(dynamicTextEnum);
        }

        foreach (DynamicTextEnum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DynamicTextEnum)))
        {
            dynamicTextEnumsAll.Add(item);
        }

        var dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable = dynamicTextEnumsAll.Except(dynamicTextEnumsInDatabase).ToList();

        if (dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable.Count == 0)
        {
            TempData["Error"] = "To update the text of a message or warning, please select it from the grid below.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AvaiableEnums = dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable;
        return View();
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Maybe try this? (*untested*)

```
ViewBag.AvaiableEnums = dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable.Select(x => 
                                  new SelectListItem() 
                                  {
                                      Text = x.ToString()
                                  });
```

Comment: Perfect. I used it as is except for setting the Value property as well. I love these one-liner LAMBDA hacks.

Comment: Such a nice solution!! Thanks a ton !!

Answer (score 18):

You could do the following

```
ViewBag.AvaiableEnums = new SelectList(dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Other answers were chosen, is there a reason NOT to do this one?

Answer (score 15):

You can maybe use a Linq statement to convert it

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myCollection = dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable
                                           .Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                                                        {
                                                            Text = i.ToString(), 
                                                            Value = i
                                                        });
```

Comment: No problem. Our answers are quite similar so at least it can be done!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert a List of objects (without Enums) to IEnumerable,
you can use a declarative style of LINQ:

```
var items = from TipoDoc t in tipoDocs
                select new SelectListItem {Value = t.Id, Text = t.Description};
```

Here, tipoDocs is a List of objects of type TipoDoc

```
public class TipoDoc
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myCollection = dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable.AsEnumerable()
```

Comment: No, this was one of the first things I did.

Answer (score -1):

Just use **.AsEnumerable()** method.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myCollection = dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable.AsEnumerable()
```

Check out here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is a duplicate of previous answer only adding a link, the other with a negative comment from the OP that it did not work for them.