# MVC5: Insert new value into populated SelectList()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag, selectlist

In my main `INV_Assets` controller of my MVC5 app, I have an method for `Edit()` which passes several populated `SelectLists()` via the ViewBag to allow users to select from all available entities for the relevant list in the other tables of my Database -- Note, if there is a better practice than passing this through the `ViewBag`, please feel free to guide me to a better way.

```
        // GET: INV_Assets/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            INV_Assets iNV_Assets = await db.INV_Assets.FindAsync(id);
            if (iNV_Assets == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Location_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Locations, "Id", "location_dept", iNV_Assets.Location_Id);
            ViewBag.Manufacturer_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Manufacturers, "Id", "manufacturer_description", iNV_Assets.Manufacturer_Id);
            ViewBag.Model_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Models, "Id", "model_description", iNV_Assets.Model_Id);
            ViewBag.Status_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Statuses, "Id", "status_description", iNV_Assets.Status_Id);
            ViewBag.Type_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Types, "Id", "type_description", iNV_Assets.Type_Id);
            ViewBag.Vendor_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Vendors, "Id", "vendor_name", iNV_Assets.Vendor_Id);
            return View(iNV_Assets);
        }
```

My lists currently populate fine, but for ease of use I want to insert a value of "Add New" into each list, that when clicked will open pop-up (partial view?) of my relevant `Create()` View for the relevant entity. For example, if the `Locations SelectList()` has "Add New" clicked, I want to open my `Create` view for Locations.

Can anyone offer an example of how to do this?

I've been looking for how to insert a new value into the `SelectList()` but most of what I seem to be coming across is using the example of forgoing the `SelectList()` instead for an `Html.DropDownList()`, though I'm not sure why?

Comment: if you had a `ViewModel` with `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, you could use `Html.DropDownListFor()` and add the "Add New" item to that, see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561(v=vs.118).aspx and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380994/convert-list-to-ienumerableselectlistitem/20381108#20381108 for details

Comment: Is it not possible to just do so using the `SelectList()`? Why is the `DropDownList()` seeming to be more popularly suggested on this issue?

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Sort of, but not quite. I ended up adding a [CREATE NEW] button next to each dropdown list for a better user experience (I did end up using a `DropDownListFor()`. The button opens (shows) a hidden form where user can enter (Ex.) a new Location, which is correctly stored in my variables of my script, but is NOT getting passed into my controller action for some reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503811/javascript-variable-storing-garbage-instead-of-value-entered-into-input-box?noredirect=1#comment45327119_28503811

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectList` class inherits `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, which are used to populate drop down lists.

Given a `ViewModel` object that has the following property:

```
public SelectList Options
{
    get
        {
            var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select((value, index) => new { value, index });
            SelectList s = new SelectList(items, "index", "value");
            return s;
        }
 }

public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
```

The `view`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOption, Model.Options, "Add New", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In order to do what you want regarding the popup, you probably need some javascript to deal with this.

If you don't want the "Add New" in the `DropDownListFor()` you would need to add it manually to your collection before returning it to the view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping Ric. I ended up using the `DropDownListFor()`, but for a better user experience decided to just use a `[CREATE NEW]` button to the right of each dropdown. I'm still having issues getting the newly entered value to be passed into my controller and saved to the DB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503811/javascript-variable-storing-garbage-instead-of-value-entered-into-input-box?noredirect=1#comment45327119_28503811

Comment: looking at that now, just wondering about the data types you are passing as it is a string and not an json object per se